# Seam Runtime error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, seam, jboss-seam

I imported a project and in problems tab appear **`Seam Runtime "jboss-seam-2.1.0.SP1" specified for Seam project "SeamSwepWeb" does not exist.`** error. I couldn't find any solution.  Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open project's Properties, in Seam Settings show Seam again, your problem will be resolved.